# Where is the YQL documentation for queries performed against remote CSVs?

Tags: javascript, csv, jsonp, google-sheets, yql

I need to fetch some data from a Google spreadsheet in a client-side web app, and I thought YQL would be a good fit, since it can grab the CSV data from Google and convert it to JSONP. I've pieced together some YQL that mostly works from various blog posts and gists and things:

```
select * from csv 
where url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=XXXX&output=csv" 
and columns="foo,bar,blah"
```

This works nicely, but I'd like to know what else I can do with it. I'm wondering, for example, if I can set up an alias for the CSV to use in a more complex query, or if I can automatically have it treat the first row as column names. I've been looking through the YQL guide, but can't find any mention of the `csv` "table," the `url` or `columns` "fields," or anything related.

Can someone provide a link to some definitive resource on querying remote CSVs with YQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "documentation" for the CSV table in YQL is pretty lightweight. It's viewable in the YQL console as:

[`desc csv`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=desc%20csv)

There you'll see the required `url` field and optional `charset` and `columns`. This is a really simple table, with the most flexibility coming from being able to choose the columns to output (the first row of data is assumed to include column headings).

If you want to do more than the base table offers, you could create an open table. This YQL team blog post shows an example of starting with a "select * from csv" call, then manipulating the results with JavaScript:

[YQL Blog: Getting stock information with YQL and open data tables](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2009/06/02/getting-stock-information-with-yql-and-open-data-tables/)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. `desc csv` prompted me to try `show tables`, which lists some interesting stuff. I'd skimmed over that YQL blog post before, but that seems like a ton of extra work for very little gain. I'll leave this open for a little while in case someone miraculously digs up some docs...